# Standard print button is inoperative in custom Report

Tags: printing, abap

My customer has reported a problem that standard ''print'' button in Z-report which a developer wrote before is not working.

How can I enable the button?

```
    MODULE user_command_0100 INPUT.
      DATA: GS_STATUS TYPE SLIS_STATUS,
      XS_STATUS LIKE GS_STATUS.

      CASE sy-ucomm.
        WHEN 'BACK' OR '%EX' OR 'RW'.
          LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
        WHEN '&RNT'.

      ENDCASE.
    ENDMODULE.
```

Comment: Is it a dynpro or a "normal" selection screen?

Comment: There is no case for the print sy-ucomm. Add one and type break-point inside this case ( analog to &RNT ),just add the instruction BREAK-POINT beneath the WHEN &PRI, and also add a WHEN PRI, and do the same there, push the pint button and have a look, what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Then button needs a usercommand assigned, which is then processed in pai. usually with a general form called get_ucomm (many developers call it similar). You also can issue /h in transaction field and then press the print-button. /h will trigger the debugger and You can inspect the report step by step.
That's all I can say without seeing the code. Hope this will help.

Comment: @knut im sharing piece of code. im not a developer but i think i should write something after 'when' to trigger.

    MODULE user_command_0100 INPUT.
      DATA: GS_STATUS TYPE SLIS_STATUS,
      XS_STATUS LIKE GS_STATUS.

      CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'BACK' OR '%EX' OR 'RW'.
      LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
    WHEN '&RNT'.

    ENDCASE.
    ENDMODULE.

Comment: Please update initial post in order to use code-highlighting features.

Comment: @Eldanar: If you post your comment under my answer, then I'm informed about your post.

Answer (score 0):

Which user command do you define in your GUI status?

If you have a standard list (what I expect when you write about a z-report), then you should define the command PRI to print the list:

[image]

If you define a screen (using the screen painter) or an ALV-Grid... then this solution will not help you.

If you don't know, what a GUI status is: Scan your source code for the command

```
SET PF-STATUS 'XXXX'.
```

Then double click on 'XXXX' and you should be directed to the status definition. There may by multiple status (and status with generic names).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen your code and for the &RNT option there's no code to execute, so if the user wants to print the button will do nothing.

```
MODULE user_command_0100 INPUT.
  DATA: GS_STATUS TYPE SLIS_STATUS,
  XS_STATUS LIKE GS_STATUS.

  CASE sy-ucomm.
    WHEN 'BACK' OR '%EX' OR 'RW'.
       LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
    WHEN '&RNT'.
       " There's no code
  ENDCASE.
ENDMODULE.
```

I've used the 'STANDARD' GUI Status from the function group 'KKBL' and '&RNT' is the code of the print button and that's why I think that is the print button you are refering in your program.

Can you post the GUI Status you are using please?

Comment: According to printscreen it is PRI and not RNT, what must be "cased".

Comment: @icbytes If you mean my screenshot: You can define your own commands in the status. The PRI is just a predefined command for ABAP-lists (which is not used in this special case).

Comment: So op's gui status is not default one?